# How to create different Panels for Add and Edit node?

Tags: nodes, panels, chaos-tool-suite

There is a default "add/edit node" panel inside the Pages content.

When I use it, it utilize the its variant for both add and edit forms.

I would need to differentiate between both of these two instead of having a common panel for both of them.

Do you have any solutions?

(My Drupal version is 7.x)

Comment: Please describe what you have tried first. The question as it is now does not comply with this site's purpose. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ok, the question is already answered. But I will make it complete!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the *node/edit* panel, create two variants, "add" and "edit."

Make sure the add variant is first.  Then add a selection rule for the add variant:

**String: URL path**  node/add/*

All paths not meeting this condition will be sent to the edit variant, which should 
give you the effect you want.