# How to create add and edit pages for content types beside to Administration

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

In my drupal installation (Drupal 7) I have various users.
What I want to do is, I want to enable somehow my users to be able to create content their own, without using the administration page.

Lets say, user clicks on a link to create an article or blog without going to administration page. The linked page contains a form for the article/blog and the user submits that form. So has been the content created.

What is the proper way to do it?
Self development of forms?
How is the URL then built?

I have found something like that
[how-to-create-different-panels-for-add-and-edit-node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133401/how-to-create-different-panels-for-add-and-edit-node)
but here the module "Pages" is probably used.

It would surprise me that something like that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply a matter of using the non-administration theme for node edit pages, there is a setting at admin/appearance, at the bottom of the page, for setting the administration theme. It also includes the following check box: "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content". Simply uncheck this to use your non-admin theme for node add/edit forms.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) That seems working quite nice. Do you know a way to customise those add-edit pages? Maybe a deletion with confirmation too? Those stuff are pretty essential for any workflow and seem missing in Drupal.

Comment: I have tried your way of working but at the end I have to mix the presentation with program logic. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid. PHP code with some HTML combined (outside of tpl or php files)

Comment: I have created a form based on tpl file with some validation and submit functions. My form is loaded from tpl file but those functions are not called at submission. What might be missing?